# PhpStorm says "PHP version Not installed" with PHP 5.6 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, installation, phpstorm

I downloaded an msi installer for PHP version 5.3 for Windows from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/). After installing it, I could have PhpStorm to recognize it without any problem (successfully adding an interpreter). Now, I want to install version 5.6. There is no msi for this version, so I've downloaded a (multiple actually) zipped file. I unpack it, then go to PhpStorm, add interpreter, and when I select the `php.exe` file, it tells me "PHP version: Not installed".

I'm running a x64 Windows 10. I've tried both the x64 (nts and non-nts) versions in the download page, as well as the x86 versions. I also tried changing the environment variable `PHPRC` in case that's what the msi installer was doing. All with no luck.

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: you should rather ask this question on PHPStorm's support forums ;)

Comment: Did https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html not work out for you? At which point did it fail?

Comment: Is that newly installed PHP actually works? What `php -i` shows if you run it in Terminal? Right now it sounds like you have errors in your PHP installation.

Comment: Try running your PHP installation by double-clicking php.exe in Explorer. It may show you some errors with your PHP installation. In my case I got and error "msvcr110.dll is missing" which was not shown in Power Shell when running php -v.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases for the error `PHP version: Not installed`, when you manually run `php.exe` it throws `MSVCR110.dll is missing`. You should install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) - with the same architecture as downloaded php interpreter.

Comment: This really saved me. New machine, couldn't figure out why PhpStorm didn't like my php.exe.. indeed it was as you said.